# minimum number of repetitions in a string

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a string of length $n$ from an alphabet $A$ with $s$ symbols.
What is the probability of having at least $k$ equal characters?

It does not seem a binomial, nor a $1-$... form, nor a bar and star.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event of some character occurring at least $k$ times is the complement of the event of each of the $s$ characters occurring at most $k-1$ times. We can count the number of such strings of length $n$, and divide by $s^n$, the number of all strings of length $n$.

The number of words with each of the $s$ characters occurring at most $k-1$ times is $n!$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ in
$$\left(1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)^s$$

As a sanity check, note that if we dropped the "at most $k-1$ times" restriction (let $k \to \infty$), we'd get the count to be $n![z^n](e^z)^s = s^n$, as expected.

So the answer (probability) is

$$1 - \frac{n![z^n]\left(1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)^s}{s^n} = 1 - n![z^n]\left(1 + (z/s) + \frac{(z/s)^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{(z/s)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)^s$$

which doesn't seem to lend itself to much simplification.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, what is the meaning of "the coefficient of z^n"? I guess you do not mean the 1/n!. Any reference would be good.

Comment: @user139803: Note that the expression is being raised to the power of $s$. For example, with $s = 4$ and $k = 3$, the first expression is $(1 + z + z^2/2)^4 = z^8/16+z^7/2+2 z^6+5 z^5+(17 z^4)/2+10 z^3+8 z^2+4 z+1$. In this expression, the coefficient of $z^7$ is $1/2$ for instance, so for $n = 7$, the answer is $1 - \frac{7!(1/2)}{4^7} = \frac{1733}{2048}$. Does that make it clear?

Comment: I see,thank you very much!